# Supporting only armv64 architecture for gstreamer ios

Tags: ios, gstreamer

I am trying to integrate gstreamer in my existing project for webm support. My app size increased by almost 16mb even by eliminating many plugins from gst_ios_init file. Is there any I can integrate gstreamer only for armv64 devices whereas my app supports all architectures. Or any other way to decrease app size further to play just webm files??

Answer (score 0):

How do you package your app?

You can remove some unused plugins (I mean those runtime loaded)..

Additionally you could ommit gst-plugins-ugly and gst-plugins-bad.. as webm is in gst-plugins-good - but you will loose some codec support (opus)..

You can still use vp8/vp9, and vorbis - as those are in base/good..

btw I guess you are only playing webm in your app .. not encoding.